# Determine the smoothly-varying principal directions of a regular surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

One can obtain two principal directions of a point (non-umbilic point) through solving a quadratic equation, i.e., $(LF-ME)(du)^2+(LG-NE)dudv+(MG-NF)(dv)^2=0$, but it is not easy to determine the information about which curvature line corresponds to which of the two principal directions from the equation above. Is there any way to tell that the principal directions derived at two different points both correspond to tangent vectors of curvature lines of the same family?

To be specific, as for the ellipsoid and an arbitrary regular surface generated from NURBS, how can I make the tangent vectors corresponding to two principal directions vary smoothly and continuously among different points on the surface, i.e., the two principal directions always correspond to the same family of curvature lines. (The principal directions of the same color in my case clearly do not constitute curvature lines of the same family)

Here I first calculate the principal directions and then the corresponding principal curvatures. Let $A = LF-ME, B = LG-NE, C = MG-NF$. Two solutions to the quadratic equation: $du:dv = \frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$, thus the principal directions can be obtained by $d\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_udu+\mathbf{r}_vdv$, and the principal curvatures are subsequently calculated by $k = \frac{Ldu+Mdv}{Edu+Fdv}$. Basis vectors at a point corresponding to two principal directions are determined just through normalization of $d\mathbf{r}$.

[Basis vectors corresponding to two principal directions at several points on an ellipsoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdxZZ.png)
[Basis vectors corresponding to two principal directions at several points on an arbitrary surface generated from NURBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QqdE.png)

Comment: The families will only be well-defined if there are no umbilic points, i.e., no points where $k_1=k_2$. Thus, you are coding one family of directions corresponding to the larger principal curvature and the other corresponding to the smaller principal curvature.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment!!! Do you mean that I should first calculate the principal curvatures and then determine each family of directions based on the larger and the other principal curvature at each point, so as to obtain a smoothly-varying field of basis vectors derived from principal directions?

Comment: Yes, precisely. But, as I said, this falls apart if there are any umbilic points. If this is a satisfactory explanation for you, I should post it as an answer.

Comment: I tried that way just now but still got some questions. I can obtain two principal curvatures through calculating the eigenvalue of the shape operator, then the principal directions are derived by $du:dv=-\frac{M-k_1F}{L-k_1E}$ and $du:dv=-\frac{M-k_2F}{L-k_2E}$, where $k_1>k_2$. However, the basis vectors I got still cannot correspond to the same family of curvature lines of, say, ellipsoid. I'm confused about this, maybe there is something I'm still not getting. I cannot attach a figure at the comment, so can I email you later to explain in detail if it's not bothering you?

Comment: The issue is that ellipsoids *do* have umbilic points. So as you cross umbilic points, the families may switch. How are you deciding what a family should be? Just what looks nice to you?

Comment: Oh thank you, I see what you mean, what troubles me is that if some physical quantities are calculated on a regular surface based on local basis vectors derived from principal directions, then how could the results be obtained when crossing such umbilic points, which may not be an issue if it is calculated in a global Cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: I do calculations in the principal directions frame all the time. But to have a continuous (smooth) global frame on the surface *without* umbilic points, you must stick with the method I described initially. You should edit your post with lots more *specific* details if you are going to continue. There is a fancy theoretical way to approach this, considering a double covering of the surface away from umbilics, with blowing up the umbilic points.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for pointing out mistakes to me. I will re-arrange my thoughts and make the question more specific! Thanks again!